# Uniform convergence in open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

I am doing Uniform convergence of functions and in this section I notice one thing that we most of the time talk about uniform convergence of sequence of functions in *Closed Interval*. Can we talk about this notion in an open intervals or intervals which are not closed.
If it is so then help me out of this problem-
Let $$f_n(x)=\frac{nx}{1+n^2x^2}.$$
This sequence of functions does not converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ as $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ does not goes towards zero on choosing X sufficiently small close to zero say $x=1/n$. But what about in case of open interval $(0,1)$, can I use same arguement here again..... I am afraid that can I use $x=1/n$ in this case too
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, since $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\frac1n\in(0,1)$, you can use the same argument with $\frac1n$. Since$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):f\left(\frac1n,n\right)=\frac12,$$$(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge uniformly to the null function and therefore, since it converges pointwise to that function, it doesn't converge uniformly *at all*.